# C# Reading through CSV file to rename multiple files with new names

Tags: c#, csv, file-rename, batch-rename

I would like to use a list of old and the corresponding new names in a CSV file(source of CSV is a Excel sheet), in order to rename files. Obviously replace the old name with the new name specified for each case.

For Example:

```
Find what                                       Replace With
C:\Users\Documents\Pump Station.doc         C:\Users\Documents\Awesome Pump Station.doc              
C:\Users\Documents\Pump Selection.doc       C:\Users\Documents\Great Pump Selection.doc
C:\Users\Documents\Pump Sizing Calc.xlsx    C:\Users\Documents\Hectic Pump Sizing Calc.xlsx
```

I am very new to coding and I am having trouble finishing this off. This is what I have so far. I do not necessarily need to even put the list user interface (which it currently does). Ultimately I would like to loop through the rows in my CSV file, check if the old name specified exists and if so, rename it to the new name specified.

I really appreciate any help in advance and sorry for any rookie errors I may have made in my code below.

```
public class OldNew
{
    public string oldFile { get; set; }
    public string newFile { get; set; }        
}

public static class OldNewService
{
    public static new List<OldNew>ReadFile(string filepath)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

        var data = from l in lines.Skip(1)
                   let split = l.Split(',')
                   select new OldNew
                   {
                       oldFile = split[0],
                       newFile = split[1],
                       };

    return data.ToList();
        }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = OldNewService.ReadFile(@"C:\Users\cch\Documents\Batch Edit\Lookup Table.csv");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You've done all the hard work and know what to do now it's just finding the  last few things: `File.Exists` to check for old files and `File.Move` to rename it. Give it a shot and let us know if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I have been trying to write a foreach loop to cycle through the list using File.Exists and File.Copy but I can't figure out how to do it so it works with my code above.

Comment: Have you figured this out? Can you post your attempt at foreach loop and I will be more than willing to help correct it.

Comment: I got this to work thanks to the comment from Shayno. I added the following to my code. It now works. Thanks for your help.

`data.ToList().ForEach(d =>
                   {
                       if (File.Exists(d.oldFile))
                       {
                           File.Copy(d.oldFile, d.newFile);
                       }
                   });

                return data.ToList();
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, a better solution would be to use a plain old foreach and not a call to `ToList().ForEach()`.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

var data = from l in lines.Skip(1)
           let split = l.Split(',')
           select new OldNew
           {
               oldFile = split[0],
               newFile = split[1],
           };

foreach(var f in data)
{
     if (File.Exists(f.oldFile)
     {
         File.Move(f.oldFile, f.newFile);
     }
}
```

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx for an explanation.

Comment: Even though both answers work. I rewrote my code to reflect your comments made. It seems to be easier to read than the first answer. Thanks for the help and for providing that source for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to get the new value of the file if an old one exists. To get the new value of the file from your list, try something like:

```
    data.ForEach(d =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.oldFile))
                {
                   File.Move(d.oldFile, d.newFile);
                }
            });
```

Wouldn't it make sense to rename the old filename if a new one exists?

Hope this helps.

Comment: File.Exists() is probably a better condition to use in the if statement.

Comment: did you mean:

`data.foreach(d =>`

because when I enter in data.ForEach, I get the following error
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Renamer.OldNew> does now contain a definition for ForEach and no extension method ForEach accepting a first argument of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Rename.OldNew> could be found (are you missing a directive or assembly reference?).

When I type it as foreach I get some other errors.

Comment: Make sure you convert data to a list before using ForEach. 
ForEach is a Linq exension to List object. 

data.ToList().ForEach(d => ... ) will work.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me. I have updated my code and it now works. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help.